# Equivalence of the two definitions of smooth maps

Tags: smooth-manifolds

**Problem**

> Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds and let $F: M\to N$ be any map. Then prove that the followings are equivalent,
>
> 1. For every $p \in M$ there exists smooth charts $(U,\varphi)$ containing $p$
>      and $(V,\psi)$ containing $F(p)$ such that $F(U)\subseteq V$ and the composite map $\psi\circ F\circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth from $\varphi(U)$ to $\psi(V)$.
> 2. For each $p\in M$ there exist smooth charts $(U,\varphi)$ containing $p$ and $(V,\psi)$ containing $F(p)$ such that $U\cap F^{-1}(V)$ is open in $M$ and the composite map $\psi\circ F\circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth from $\varphi(U\cap F^{-1}(V))$ to $\psi(V)$,

**My Attempt**

I think that $(1)\implies (2)$ is easy. It is so because if we assume $(1)$ then for every $p\in M$, there exists smooth charts $(U,\varphi)$ containing $p$
and $(V,\psi)$ containing $F(p)$ such that $F(U)\subseteq V$. Now $$F(U)\subseteq V\implies F^{-1}(F(U))\subseteq F^{-1}(V)\implies U\subseteq F^{-1}(F(U))\subseteq F^{-1}(V)$$ and hence $U\cap F^{-1}(V)=U$, which is open in $M$. Thus we have shown that for every $p \in M$ there exists smooth charts $(U,\varphi)$ containing $p$ and $(V,\psi)$ containing $F(p)$ such that $U\cap F^{-1}(V)$ is open in $M$ and the composite map $\psi\circ F\circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth from $\varphi(U\cap F^{-1}(V))$ to $\psi(V)$. hence we are done.

**Where I am stuck**

To prove that $(2)\implies (1)$, I think it is enough to show the existence of a chart $(V,\psi)$ containing $F(p)$ such that $F(U)\subseteq V$ because then 
 $U\cap F^{-1}(V)=U$. However, to prove this the problem I am facing is that the hypothesis of $(2)$ implies that $U\cap F^{-1}(V)\ne \emptyset$. But how can I use it to show that $F(U)\subseteq V$?

Comment: Note that $U \cap F^{-1}(V) \neq \emptyset$ always, since it contains $p$

Comment: @57Jimmy: Didn't I mention it too?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant something else :)

Comment: @57Jimmy: No problem.

Comment: In general, though, you cannot expect $F(U) \subseteq V$ ($U$ could even be the whole space), that's why you have to change the chart. The $U$ and $V$ of $(1)$ are not necessarily the same as the $U$ and $V$ of $(2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ is correct. Hint for $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$: restrict the chart $U$ to $U':=U \cap F^{-1}(V)$. The important thing is that there is some chart, so you can use $U'$ instead of $U$, since an open subset of a chart is still a chart.

Comment: So you say that instead of $(U,\varphi)$ we consider $(U',\varphi|_{U'})$, right?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant

Comment: Nice. Sorry if this was a trivial question.

Comment: It was not: manifolds are a complicated object to study at the beginning, because of the many possible definitions of everything.